# jQuery Flexslider not loading every time

Tags: jquery, html, flexslider

I have a FlexSlider on a clients website. The problem is that it does not load every time. Sometimes it just goes blank. The area that it should be.

Now this is the code that produces the slider:

```
<script src="http://xlprint.no/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){$("#slider").flexslider({animation: "slide",slideDirection: "vertical"});});
</script>
<div class="eightcol" id="slider_container">
    <div id="slider" class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li>
                <img src="http://bildeserver.nconel.no/1356/slider/b7be410db5f05502f4b552a200e1f3de.png" alt="">
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="http://bildeserver.nconel.no/1356/slider/a0204e4cce74ea2d4f33723710eca17a.png" alt="">
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="http://bildeserver.nconel.no/1356/slider/3576f00127fc13ffa732e33237c5a7bf.png" alt="">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

It runs [jQuery FlexSlider v1.8](http://flex.madebymufffin.com).

How can I make this more stabile?

**It can be tested at**: http://xlprint.no/

Comment: when it "just goes blank" what errors are shown on the JavaScript console ? and works fine for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/WENv5/

Comment: This link is broken http://dev.xlprint.no/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js
Try your http://xlprint.no/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js. Its working

Comment: Same issue. I get no errors on the console.

Answer (score 4):

This may be a timing issue, flexslider may require the images to be loaded when it is called so it can work off their attributes, remember that $(document).ready() fires after the DOM has finished loading whilst $(window).load() fires after all images on the page have loaded - giving you intermittent results if they are cached etc, replace:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... });
```

with

```
$(window).load(function(){ ... });
```

Incidentally, the working example on github also uses $(window).load.

Comment: I'm not sure if this resolved the original poster's issue, but it helped me with one of mine. +1

Answer (score 1):

I know that it seems ridiculous...
But I had a similar issue to my flexslider and this solved (ugly, but solved)

```
setInterval(function () { $('.flexslider').resize(); }, 100);
```